# Is it possible to add Several bgcolor to one HTML page,Not background-color

Tags: html, css

[In this  page used 2 color as bgcolor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZagB1.png)

Comment: Hi and Welcome on SO. I vote to close this question beacuse it is absolutely unclear. I'll suggest to reade [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to do, but you can setup multiple div as background like this:

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}

.background.bg1 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
}
.background.bg2 {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .5);
}
.background.bg3 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="background bg1"></div>
  <div class="background bg2"></div>
  <div class="background bg3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean half of a div one color, second other color?

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, red 50%, blue 50%);
}
```

or you want it vertical?

```css
    body {
      padding: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50%, blue 50%);
    }
```

or you want it to gradually move from first to other?

```css
    body {
      padding: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      background: linear-gradient(to left, red , blue );
    }
```

or vertically?

```css
    body {
      padding: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red , blue );
    }
```